# SQL - How do I get name using a number from a different table?

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

Below is my create tables for a database using SQL. 
I can't figure out how to get a name displayed for both ID and LIKED from the likes table.

This assignment should be simple, be able to display the names of people that like each other. There is a data entry form that requires IDs to be entered for the people that like each other, but then I have to display the names of both of the people that like each other.... I hope I didn't make this confusing. 
Is it possible for some SQL code to display the names of who likes who.

```
CREATE TABLE person 
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(50)
) engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE likes 
(
    ID INT,
    LIKED INT,
    constraint likesPK primary key(ID,LIKED),
    constraint personFK foreign key(ID) references person(ID)
    on delete cascade on update cascade,
    constraint nameFK foreign key(LIKED) references person(ID)
    on delete cascade on update cascade
) engine=innodb;
```

Example of what I have tried to do but needs one more column to display the person "LIKED":

```
     select B.id, B.name, A.lIKED from likes A, person B where A.id=B.id AND A.id = 1;
```

Comment: Your query is missing a join between the two tables.

Comment: where a.id = b.id looks like a join to me.

Answer (score 3):

First, I wave my finger in your general direction.  Programming requires precision and your phrase, "using sql" was vague.  If you meant sql server say so.  In fact, edit your post and add the appropriate tag.

Second, your on delete cascades are in the wrong place.  In fact, in this scenario, on delete cascades are probably a very bad idea.

Third, what was that again?  Oh yes your question.  How do I show people who like each other?  Probably something like this:

```
select p1.whatever, p2.whatever
from person p1  -- this would be me
join likes l1 on p1.id = l1.id  -- this is who I like, which is you
join likes l2 on l1.liked = l2.id -- this is who you like, which is me
join person p2 on l2.id = p2.id  -- this is you
etc
```

By the way, I didn't think it was simple.

Comment: "...I wave my finger in your general direction" is going to be my new favorite phrase for the next week...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select b.id, b.name, (select name from person where id = a.liked) 
from likes a join person b 
on a.id = b.id
where b.id = some id AND b.id = a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `like` table should have two references to the `person` table (making it an intermediate/pivot table); basically, one "like-ee" and one "like-or". So `like` should probably look like this:

```
like
--------------
ID int
PersonWhoLikedID int
PersonWhoWasLikedID int
```

Then your query turns into this:

```
SELECT B.name, C.name AS `Liked Person`
FROM likes
LEFT JOIN person B ON likes.PersonWhoLikedID = B.ID
LEFT JOIN person C ON likes.PersonWhoWasLikedID = C.ID
```

Comment: do not need another col. id is person who 'liked' unless you specify let the likes table id be a primary auto key for table Likes. that is a good idea